# Mysterious error messages in Eclipse (using StatET/R)

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

All,

I'm not sure when this started, but I've noticed that just about any time I add to an R script in Eclipse, I get a warning in Eclipse's error log that looks like the following:

```
Unhandled/Unknown code of R AST node:
Code: 0x1000000
Node: <- (195, 70) Line 4 at offset 195 (can be wrong, if out of synch):
```

All of my code appears to execute fine, but I would like to know what sort of problem this refers to. I'm running R-2.13.0 and Eclipse 3.7 in a Windows 32 bit environment. Any clues are much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: You also need to say which version of StatET, and which version of the StatET dependencies.

Comment: Sure, I've got StatET 0.10.0, Java 1.6.0, rj 0.5.5, and rJava 0.9-1.

Comment: It looks like you have an up-to-date version.  I've never seen this error message, either in StatET 0.10 or in the more recent v2.0.  Have you by any chance added something in your .RProfile that doesn't work properly?